# How to multiple search on the same string using regular expression in perl?

Tags: regex, json, perl, search

I need to get the different kinds of information from a website. It is knowing that the format is in this way (all on one line):

```
"name":"BLAHBLAH","contact":{"phone":"12345","twitter":"BLAHBLAH"},
  "location": "address":"NOTTELLING","lat":10,"lng":10,"postalCode":"1234",
  "city":"BLAH","state":"BLAH","country":"BLAH"},
  "categories":[{"id":"BLAH","name":"BLAH"}]
```

Some of these profiles will have one or two blocks missing, like no name, no city, etc.
I tried the code like this:

```
   #get name
   $content =~ m!","name":"(.*?)","contact":!igs;
   say ("name:", $1) unless ($1 eq '');
   #get street 
   if ($content =~ m!\},"location":\{"address":"(.*?)","lat":!igs)
   {say ("street:", $1) unless ($1 eq '');}
   #get city 
   if ($content =~ m!,"city":"(.*?)","state":!igs)
   {say ("city:", $1) unless ($1 eq '');}
   #get state
   if ($content =~ m!,"state":"(.*?)","country":!igs)
   {say ("state:", $1) unless ($1 eq '');}
```

Then I realize that when i use the repeated pattern (e.g.

```
"city":"(.*?)","state":!igs
```

and

```
"state":"(.*?)","country":!igs)
```

the result will be not accurate. (I guess perl jump over the string after the first time it gets to ,"state") My question is how this happens? and how do i fix it?

Comment: That looks like JSON. Have you tried using a JSON parser?

Comment: no, can you provide more details or a tutorial please? I'm new to everything

Comment: Please use Google. JSON is a very common format these days, you'll find lots of info on using it with Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks a lot like **JSON** to me -- betcha it is.  Find out and you can turn the whole string into a hash with fields `name`, `contact`, `location`, etc. using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

use JSON::XS;
use YAML::XS;

my $json = <<HERE;
{
  "name":"BLAHBLAH","contact":{"phone":"12345","twitter":"BLAHBLAH"},
  "location": {"address":"NOTTELLING","lat":10,"lng":10,"postalCode":"1234",
  "city":"BLAH","state":"BLAH","country":"BLAH"},
  "categories":[{"id":"BLAH","name":"BLAH"}]
}
HERE

print $json;

my $hash_ref = decode_json($json);

print Dump $hash_ref->{location};
```

I had to add a `{` between `"location":` and `"address":`, guessing that was a typo on your end.  Anyway, then the output is:

```
{
  "name":"BLAHBLAH","contact":{"phone":"12345","twitter":"BLAHBLAH"},
  "location": {"address":"NOTTELLING","lat":10,"lng":10,"postalCode":"1234",
  "city":"BLAH","state":"BLAH","country":"BLAH"},
  "categories":[{"id":"BLAH","name":"BLAH"}]
}
---
address: NOTTELLING
city: BLAH
country: BLAH
lat: 10
lng: 10
postalCode: '1234'
state: BLAH
```

I used `YAML::XS` for brevity; you don't need that.  If you don't see the point yet, consider:

```
print $hash_ref->{location}->{state};
```

gives you `BLAH`.

JSON is "javascript object notation", and it is a common data interchange format for OO languages (such as perl), especially online.

Comment: Great solution and great explanation. This is very helpful to a newbie like me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, a JSON parser is definitely The Right Way to go about it - you've only described one of the many, many pitfalls in trying to parse JSON with regexes.

To answer the actual question about regexes, though:

When you use a regex with the `/g` modifier in scalar context (your use is in scalar context because the result is being assigned to a scalar), it only processes the first match, then stops and waits to see if you'll call the same regex again on the same string to get the next match.  Because of this, regexes with `/g` are generally used in scalar context with a `while` rather than an `if`:

```
$ perl -E 'while ("This is an example string." =~ /\b(\w{2,6})\b/g) { say $1 }'
This
is
an
string
```

The other way to use a regex with the `/g` modifier is to put it in array context (by assigning the result to an array).  In this case, it will return the list of all matches at once:

```
$ perl -E '@matches = "This is an example string." =~ /\b(\w{2,6})\b/g; say join ",", @matches;'
This,is,an,string
```

If you're not doing one of these two things (looping on the result in scalar context or using a full list of matches in array context), you probably don't want to use the `/g` regex modifier.

Comment: All right, so is there any way to reset the search position after a use of /g? For example, I got all the matches of text "abc" in one content by using /g. Then how do i search all the matches of "defghi" in the same content?

Comment: Just do it again.  After a match fails (e.g., because you hit the end of the string), it gets reset to the start of the string.